# What is the term for a given interpretation of a fossil record?

Tags: terminology, palaeontology

There exists a term, that I have heard and forgotten it appears, for taking a described species in paleontology and creating a version of what it was like in life.

For example, a prior `[insert this term here]` for T Rex had it upright and dragging it's tail, while a more recent `[insert term again]` has shown a much more horizontal and rigid body plan.

I know you 'describe' it formally when you identify it from remains, and 'mount' when you set up a specific set of remains. But what is it when you interpret those remains to a specific form?

Comment: Realization? Re-creation? Interpretation? Depiction? Illustration? Imagination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you are looking for is **reconstruction** (as in 
[Forensic facial reconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forensic_facial_reconstruction)).

You can find it used on the wikipedia articles for [Fossil cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil_Cave) and for [Transitional fossil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitional_fossil) or in the post [In reconstructions, how are various shapes of facial features determined from skull only?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/55842/in-reconstructions-how-are-various-shapes-of-facial-features-determined-from-sk) for examples.